# Removing categorical predictors with mode frequency above certain threshold

Tags: categorical-data, data-preprocessing

Is there a rule of thumb for dropping certain categorical predictors if the most frequent value in the column is above a certain threshold? For example, should I drop a column/predictor if more than 95% of the values are the same category?

What would be the proper way of dealing with such kind of columns? Should the rare values be checked with the target variable?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to come up with a good, general rule of thumb for this.

Imagine a disease/condition that is perfectly determined by variation in one gene and is very rare. Suppose 0.01% of the population has the disease; it is caused by an allele that is also only present in that 0.01% of the population (to simplify a bit). It would not make sense to ignore the gene predicting the disease just because 99.99% of the values were identical - that 0.01% is incredibly important! In this case that little variation in the data would lead to a perfect predictions of disease incidence.

So at the very least, a decision about whether to omit such a predictor should consider the causal connection to the response, as well as the distribution of the response.